# ngx-material-timepicker v5.4.3 - modify the style of the timepicker-field

Tags: angular, angular-material, timepicker

I am using ngx-material-timepicker field and I want to modify the following:
[image] 
1. remove the up and down arrow in hour and minute
2. instead of just a line at the bottom, I want to make it as a box
So it will be look like this:
[image]

I'm using the code below

```
 <ngx-timepicker-field [defaultTime]="'11:11 am'"></ngx-timepicker-field>
```